# for-loop not working after upgrade of Pandas/Numpy

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I was running one python script whose basic idea is to scan the directory for text files like:

```py
files = glob.glob("*.txt")
files
-------
output:
['name_6-076_01.txt',
 'name_6-077_00.txt',
 'name_6-077_01.txt',
 'name_6-078_00.txt',
 'name_6-078_01.txt',
 'name_6-079_00.txt']
```

Please observe `*077*.txt` it has two entries `_00 and _01` same with `*078*.txt` (i have some list of files as such, some even more).

I am trying to put these files (from `*077*`) into a single excel worksheet (consider exporting to excel).

```py
lane_spot = ['Spot_6-076_01', 'Spot_6-077_00', 'Spot_6-077_01', 'Spot_6-078_00', 'Spot_6-078_01', 'Spot_6-079_00']
```

`spotlanes()` is a function that returns a dataframe.

`writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'Summary_{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")}.xlsx')`

I am successful in this.
But the upgrade to Pandas(0.23.4 to 1.0.3) has disrupted everything.

below is the code that worked for me without any issues:

```py
for i in range(len(files)):
    try:
        if (files[i][:-7] == files[i-1][:-7]):
            sheet = lane_spot[i-1]
            lane = spotlanes(files[i])
            lane[f'{lane_spot[i]}'] = [f'{lane_spot[i]}', f'{lane_spot[i]}']
            lane.set_index(f'{lane_spot[i]}',append=True, inplace=True)
            lane.index = lane.index.swaplevel(0,1)
            lane = lane.rename_axis(['Spot','Method'])
            lane.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=f'{sheet}',index=True, startrow=3)
            writer.save()
        else:
            sheet = lane_spot[i]
            lane = spotlanes(files[i])
            lane[f'{lane_spot[i]}'] = [f'{lane_spot[i]}', f'{lane_spot[i]}']
            lane.set_index(f'{lane_spot[i]}',append=True, inplace=True)
            lane.index = lane.index.swaplevel(0,1)
            lane = lane.rename_axis(['Spot','Method'])
            lane.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=f'{sheet}',index=True)
            writer.save()
    except IndexError:
        print("EOF")
```

same code tested outside and as desired:

```py
In [14]: for i in range(len(files)):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         if (files[i][:-7] == files[i-1][:-7]):
    ...:             print(f'sheet{i-1} appended', lane_spot[i])
    ...:         else:
    ...:             print(f'sheet{i}', lane_spot[i])
    ...:
    ...:     except IndexError:
    ...:         print("fo")
    ...:
    ...:
sheet0 Spot_6-076_01
sheet1 Spot_6-077_00
sheet1 appended Spot_6-077_01
sheet3 Spot_6-078_00
sheet3 appended Spot_6-078_01
sheet5 Spot_6-079_00
sheet5 appended Spot_6-079_01
sheet7 Spot_6-080_00
sheet7 appended Spot_6-080_01
sheet9 Spot_7-008_00
sheet9 appended Spot_7-008_01
sheet11 Spot_7-009_00
```

So, basically, it is not writing anything into the excel sheet after the first iteration. It worked fine and the sheets were getting added fine.
can you advise if there is anything with the excel engine, I have `openpyxl` and also `xlsxwriter`, though I havent used them at the same time.

I need the output into an excel file with the contents in the respective excel sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the `XLSXWriter` and did some minor code changes. Looks like there is a conflict between, `openpyxl` and `XLSXWriter`

```
if:
    ...
    sheet = lane_spot[i-1][:-3]
    ...
else:
    ...
    sheet = lane_spot[i][:-3]
    ...
```

this fixed!.